# Creating a React Component with a click, need to differentiate every Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, components, clone

I've made such a table to put articles with their respective prices, quantity... What's more there's a button and with every click it's created a new article. (put a photo to see it clearer)[image]

The fact is that I need a way to differentiate every line, what i say is that in the square "Num" there should be 1,2,3... this is very important to me because later I need to send the information to a database, but my problem is I don't know how to differentiate every line. Here I put the code

```js
class LinArt extends Component{
constructor(){
  super()
  this.state = {
    quan:2,
    price:20,
    dto:10,
    count:1
  }
  this.newArt = this.newArt.bind(this)
}

newArt(){
  this.setState({count:this.state.count+1})
  }
  showArt(){
    const total = (this.state.cant * this.state.preu) * (1-(this.state.dto/100));
    let lines =[];
    for(let i=0; i < this.state.count; i++){
      lines.push(
        <div key={i}>
          
        <TextField type="number" disabled={true} value={this.state.count} label="Num"/>
       <TextField label="Descripció" variant="outlined"/>
       <TextField type="number" label="Cant" value={this.state.quan}/>
       <TextField type="number" label="Price" value={this.state.price}/>
       <TextField  type="number" label="Dto" value={this.state.dto }}/>
       <TextField  type="number" disabled={true} value={total} label="Total"/>
       <TextField type="number" disabled={true} value="21" label="IVA"/>
        <br/><hr/>
        </div>
      )
    }
    return linies || null;
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
      
       {this.showArt()}
<Button onClick={this.newArt}>New article </Button>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Thank you for your attention, I appreciate so much your help!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, if you want the num column to increment, you should add `i + 1` increment variable as the value to your num field so as it runs the loop, it gives the incremented value and starts from `1` rather than `0`. Like so,

`<TextField type="number" disabled={true} value={i + 1} label="Num"/>`

Comment: This method is perfect to diferenciate de number of each article. The problem is that i need the possibility of putting diferent prices, quantity... to each article